# Looking for the biggest number before and after 'i' in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sorry if the title is confusing. Here's a better explanation:
So basically what I need to do is iterate through every number in list and print the biggest number west (list[0:i]) and the biggest number east. If the biggest number is smaller than i, we print i. So for list [1, 3, 2, 4, 3] the output should be:
1 4
3 4 
3 4
4 4
4 3

I thought my code was correct but it doesn't work for the last number in list, is anyone able to help?

'a' is the list in my code

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 4, 3] 
for i in a:
    west = a[0:i]
    east = a[i:int(len(a))]
    if max(west) > i:
        print(max(west))
    else:
        print(i)
    if max(east) > i:
        print(max(east))
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: your question is unclear, but `i` is the element in `a` and not the index, you know that?

Comment: If I am in the southern hemisphere, is west left or right?

Comment: What does `it doesn't work for the last number in list` mean?

Comment: Add `print('west:{}, i:{}, east:{}'.format(west, i, east))` just before the first condition to help you diagnose the problem.

Comment: @wwii you are right, using west and east wasn't a good idea. Also I should've been more clear on what "it doesn't work for the last number in list" means. Thanks for your input, my mistake was that I thought i was the index in a. I have no idea why I didn't notice that though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
for i in range(len(a)): 
    print(max(a[:i+1]))
    print(max(a[i:]))
```

You are not iterating over the indices in your original code; and thus the partition does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The only mistake in your code is the `for i in a` loop, which loops throgh `i = 1,3,2,4,3` and not `i=0,1,2,3,4`

The following piece of code works

```
a=[1,3,2,4,3]
for i in range(len(a)) :
    print max(i,max(a[:i+1]))
    print max(i,max(a[i:]))
```

Comment: You could probably use [enumerate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to clear your code up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

this may work... not fully tested but it looks correct

```
a = [1, 3, 2, 4, 3]
for i in a[:-1]:
    west = a[0:i]
    east = a[i:int(len(a))]
    if max(west) > i:
        print(max(west))
    else:
        print(i)
    if max(east) > i:
        print(max(east))
    else:
        print(i)
num = a[-1]
west = a[0:-1]
if max(west) > num:
    print(max(west))
else:
    print(str(a[-1]))
print(str(a[-1]))
```

Output: 1 4 3 4 4 4 4 3